# Streaming EEG data from Qstreamer to Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to stream the data from Qstreamer directly to Unity through TCP/IP
QStreamer is QUASAR’s data acquisition software with an intuitive user interface to control the system and acquire data.

https://gist.github.com/danielbierwirth/0636650b005834204cb19ef5ae6ccedb

I have tried using this guy's script but i dont know how to set it up

Comment: Hmm so you want us to set it up for you? I do not think that is gonna happen. Take a look at [what you can ask on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It looks like the author of that gist is pretty active. Maybe you could post a comment there and try to get an answer from him?

Comment: lol i want to know how should i setup i am new to unity that's why @AliKanat